# How do I create an email for which Outlook does not wrap the text?

Tags: html, css, outlook, pre

I'm trying to send some log output as email, but Outlook keeps wrapping it, making it almost unreadable (it contains some very long lines).

Basically I just want the text to be displayed like Notepad++ does with word wrap turned off.

I tried (in various combinations):

- Plain text email
- HTML email
- `<pre>` tag
- `<div>` with white-space: nowrap
- overflow: scroll

Nothing works, Outlooks insists on wrapping. And never shows a horizontal scroll bar (although I could even live with a solution that cuts the text off without showing a scrollbar).

Comment: Are you saying there is no email (outside or created by you) that Outlook does not wrap?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko opposite: it always wraps

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I said - double negative "no email.. does not wrap" = "always wraps". If it is only your emails that misbehave, have you tried to compare to the emails that work as expected?